# Threading-related issue - Python 3 (Discord bot)

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I tried to look up this issue, but it seems like I've done something I can no longer look up on my own, so I'll need your guys' help. This will probably be a rather difficult one, but I really hope that someone will help me with this one!

The code: (Apologies for the messy code beforehand)

```
import json, requests, threading, discord, math, random
from requests import adapters
from requests_testadapter import Resp
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = 'SOMETOKENIDTHATICANTREVEALANDYOUKNOWWHY'
BOT_PREFIX = ('!')
url_api = 'http://api.lambdawars.com/player/matches/list/{}'  # input the 
SteamID64
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.async_event
class LocalFileAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def build_response_from_file(self,request,steamid):
        file_path = request.url_api.format(steamid)[7:]
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            buff = bytearray(file.read())
            resp = Resp(buff)
            r = self.build_response(request, resp)

            return r

    def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        return self.build_response_from_file(request)

requests_session = requests.session()
requests_session.mount('file://', LocalFileAdapter())
old_response = ''
monitor_ids = []

@client.command(name='addID')
async def monitoring(steamid):
    global old_response
    monitor_ids.append(steamid)
    while True:
        await client.say("Loading results for: " + steamid + "...")
        print('Loading results for: ' + steamid)
        url_new = url_api
        response = requests_session.get(url_new.format(steamid))
        if response != old_response:
            old_response = response
        try:
            global idresponse
            idresponse = str('-\nPlayer ID {} **' + response.json()['matches'][0]['end_state'] + "** on **" +
        response.json()['matches'][0]['start_date'] + "** on map **" + response.json()['matches'][0][
            'map'] + "**. \nGame mode: **" + response.json()['matches'][0]['mode'] + "**, type: **" +
        response.json()['matches'][0]['type'] + "**. \nThe match lasted **" + str(
        math.floor(float(response.json()['matches'][0]['duration']) / 60)) + "** minutes").format(id)
        except TypeError:
            print("duration type error - bust be a number")
            # await client.say(' | '.join(god_damnit_sandern))
            await client.say(random.choice["God damnit, Sandern! That match failed to be recorded properly. " + '<:hmm:453711378067226630>',
                                       "God damnit, Sandern! He stole your match data!" + '<:hmm:453711378067226630>',
                                       "God damnit, Sandern! Your match data was not found, it's all his fault!" + '<:hmm:453711378067226630>'])
        except KeyError:
            print("Wrong SteamID64 number!")
            # await client.say('|'.join(god_damnit_sandern))
            await client.say("-"
                         "\nThis (" + steamid + ") isn't SteamID64. <:hardfacepalm:453711378272878592> "
                                           "\nCheck for typos?")
        except IndexError:
            print("This SteamID64 has no game records.")
            await client.say('-'
                         '\nThis user (' + steamid + ') has never ever played Lambda Wars online yet! <:youserious:453711378687983626>'
                                                '\nWhat a loser!')

            await client.say(idresponse)

thread = threading.Thread(target=monitoring)
thread.start()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I was working on a Discord bot. The idea was to make a command, namely `!addID 76561197995806465` where the ID itself is a SteamID64 for tracking API results on the following page: http://api.lambdawars.com/player/matches/list/76561197995806465

This is basically a JSON result with some of its pieces taken out from the first bit (['matches'][0][{a key, such as "duration" or "start_date"}]).

The plan was to make it automatically get the results, as soon as these results are given, using the following piece in the monitoring method:

```
if response != old_response:
    old_response = response
```

It does work as a command and makes the Discord bot leave a message when given the SteamID64 and an optional number, such as 1 (0 being default):

`LamBOTa Wars: -
Player ID 76561198223952276 lost on Sat, 16 Jun 2018 10:23:49 GMT on map hlw_breakout. 
Game mode: destroyhq, type: FFA. 
The match lasted 13 minutes`

(If you would like to see the code for this one, I'll post it)

So when I run my code, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'Command' object is not callable
```

Help would be really appreciated!

Also before you ask, yes, I am a newb at programming in general. That's my first experience with bots.

Comment: Why are you even using threading? It doesn't seem like you need it. (Asynchronous != use threading). And why is there a `@async_event` decorator for `LocalFileAdapter`? You should probably read the docs and see what they are for. Side note: you shouldn't use the requests library, as it's not meant to work asynchronously, use aiohttp.

Comment: Well, a colleague suggested using it. It did work with the Telegram bot (PyTelegramBotAPI), and it does receive live changes, so I thought using it for Discord bot too. Problem is, the structure of the bots is different, so perhaps that's one of the issues.

EDIT: Oh wait, so I shouldn't use async+await with threading?

Comment: @abccd used the `@async_event` because it gave me a coroutine issue, so I looked it up, and it was dealt with the `@async_event` decorator.
Again, please don't be angry at me here, I'm still a newb :p

Comment: What you should do right now is to remove the two threading line. And research on how you would change your current requests code to use aiohttp. (And also remove the `@client.async_event` decorator). If I remember correctly, Telegram bot isn't asynchronous.

Comment: @abccd, nonono, It's not for the Telegram bot! This one's for the Discord bot.

And thanks, I'll look into aiohttp.

Comment: @abccd, okay, cool. It stopped giving me the crashes, but it's stuck on loading the results, once the !addID command is called:

    `Loading results for: 76561198242815160
    Loading results for: 76561198242815160 
    Loading results for: 76561198242815160 
    Loading results for: 76561198242815160`. Suppose I could try debugging it, but I think it's not doing anything because... well I actually can't understand why it's stuck on gathering results as they are always the same, until the ID plays a match.

Comment: The line `await client.say(idresponse)` should probably be unindented. And if you are still using requests, things might not function properly, since requests made by the library requests are blocking. (P.s. don't assume I'm angry, trust me I'm not, it's just the unintentional stately tone that I'm responding with here)

Comment: @abccd, oh and one more thing. I just realized you meant that I have to change the `requests_session = requests.session()` to `requests_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()`, right?
But if I do that, how do I mount the `('file://',LocalFileAdapter())` bit?

Comment: Sorry, I can't exactly help you on your last question, since I'm not very familiar with aiohttp and requests for that matter (I don't web scrap often). You can try reading their docs and hopefully find something similar?

Comment: @abccd Thanks again. I'll try something else then.